# Increment label printing excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on setting up increment printing for a series of labels printed from excel. there are four label numbers per sheet, with duplicate values ( total of 8 labels per page ). Ive attached a screen shot of the file.https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfSoz.png. The first label number, 26000, is the one that will be referenced in the script, the rest updated by a formula to add +1 to the number. I want the first number to be repopulated each time a sheet is printed for any given quantity of sheets. I've put together the script below, but each time i print it does not display the correct number. Instead of continuing the next series at the top,26005, it displays 5. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Sub PrintNext5()

```
Dim xCount As Variant
Dim xScreen As Boolean
Dim I As Integer
On Error Resume Next

xCount = Application.InputBox("Please enter the number of copies you want to print:")
If TypeName(xCount) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
If (xCount = "") Or (Not IsNumeric(xCount)) Or (xCount < 1) Then
    MsgBox "error entered, please enter again"
    
Else
    xScreen = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For I = 1 To xCount
        ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Value = Range("C3" + 5)
        ActiveSheet.PrintOut
    Next
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = xScreen
End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I can understand, your counter isnot counting correctly

try init your counter in the first value required, to (the fist plus the count of labels)

Check the code

Good Luck

```
Sub PrintNext5()

    Dim xCount As Variant
    Dim xScreen As Boolean
    Dim I As Integer
    On Error Resume Next

    xCount = Application.InputBox("Please enter the number of copies you want to print:")
    If TypeName(xCount) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
        If (xCount = "") Or (Not IsNumeric(xCount)) Or (xCount < 1) Then
            MsgBox "error entered, please enter again"

        Else
            xScreen = Application.ScreenUpdating
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            'your counter I in this case, should begin in 26000 and xCount should be xCount + 26000
            'you can try assign name to a cell in order to call it as name
            'begins = Sheets("otherSheet").Range("A1") <--Catch the first value from a cell
            For I = 26000 To xCount + 26000
            ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Value = I
            ActiveSheet.PrintOut
            I = I + 5 '<-- Your picture has 4 labels 1, 2, 3, 4, we are in 1 plus 4 = 5, next round begin in 5, 6, 7, 8,
            Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = xScreen
    End If
End Sub
```